# Flutter firebase packages not working in release mode

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

My flutter firebase packages seem to work in debug mode but not in release mode,

So I've made an app that uses *firebase* on the backend and while I was developing it in debugging mode everything worked fine including authentication *firestore* reading and writing and pretty much everything else.
then when I build it in release mode all the functions that concern the firebase backend
seem to not work at all or just time out.
in debug mode everything still works fine.
This problem has persisted for a few days now and has held the development back alot. note: during compiling the terminal gives a warning for cloud firestore and authentication packages that they use a deprecated api.

any help would be highly appreciated
thanks.

Comment: Have you added the SHA1 of release fingerprint to the Firebase Project Settings? You need to add three fingerprints. One for debug, one for release under your keystore, one for publishing app to google play which can be obtained from Play Console.

Comment: no i havent can u please suggest how I might do these 3 steps? thanks

Comment: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9137403?hl=en

Comment: You can obtain your debug and release fingerprints through the docs on https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth
For releasing on google play (if you have enabled google play to manage app signing), you can find SHA1 under App Integrity section.

Comment: this issue was not solved i did add the sha1 codes to the firebase settings and still the app doesnt execute any of the functions in release mode but does in debug mode, i also changed the rules to allow read write if false... still no solution

Comment: if false? That will break the cloud firestore. Try it with if true.

Comment: Also check the release AndroidManifest.xml and confirm whether you have added the internet permissions.

Comment: I have changed the firestore rules to allow read, write;

Comment: yes of course the android manifest file has the internet permission it needs, tomorrow I will try to download the Googleservices.json file and add it again to my project, since maybe after adding the sha1 codes the Google services configuration json file needs to be changed. if anyone has any other ideas please share since this issue seems to be persisting through any attempted fixes...

Comment: Have the issue solved?